# Vertical Align Image inside Anchor

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a `<ul>` with two columns

Code:

```
<li class="clearfix">
<div class="product-copy">
 Product Content Here
</div>
<a href="">
    "PRODUCT IMAGE HERE"
</a>
</li>
```

The `.product-copy` expands to content in height, width is fixed.

I want to be able to vertically align the image within the anchor to center. So no matter how large in height the `.product-copy` is, the image in the right column will always be centered.

Please note that I am still a new user so couldn't type the proper image html within the anchor but there is a html image within the anchor.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This article might be of help http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score -2):

You can try some CSS like

```
.product_img { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; }
```

This is from memory, you may need to remove the position:absolute; from the class.

Simply add the class to the img tag and this will vertically align your image to the middle of the div.

```
<img srv="my_image.png" class="product_image" />
```

Comment: Do you mean li a img? there are no images within .product-copy

Comment: It would be a new class specifically for the image. I tend to use my CSS files for this but you can also include the CSS into the style tag of the img element. You can try assigning the class to the a tag also if you're not implicitly using an img element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that didn't work, all images appear to the top of the page.. I wish I could show you the site but it's still on local server. Don't worry about this though we are deciding to leave it as is :-)

Comment: @Judy Vialoux you can also try the margin-top and margin-bottom in the class, in my current site I use the method posted (I checked) and it works perfectly for vertical alignment of images :)

Comment: +! Worked for me. Thanks!